# How to get "has_b_frames" video property in NReco?

Tags: asp.net, nreco

I try to get "has_b_frames" value of video, but failed at select xml node. 
The code:

```
var videoInfo = new FFProbe();
var root = videoInfo.GetMediaInfo(filename).Result.CreateNavigator();
root.Select("/ffprobe/streams");
root.MoveToNextAttribute();
```

the value of root is
[root value 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAfvp.png) and [root value 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlC7O.png) respectively, 
and the value of outerxml is [outerxml value with XML visualizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLZnn.png).

So how can I get the attribute "has_b_frames" ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use appropriate XPath selector, something like this:

```
var mediaInfo = videoInfo.GetMediaInfo(filename);
var has_b_frames = mediaInfo.Result.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode(
  "/ffprobe/streams/stream[@index=\"0\"]/@has_b_frames")?.Value;
```

Comment: Can I ask another quesion? 
What the difference between has_b_frames="2"  and has_b_frames="1" ?

Comment: @honeytoast most likely this is value from https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.2/structAVCodecContext.html#a686a77363668795c15c87b532cc455fa